# Font not displaying correctly in cyrillic on some occasions

Tags: html, css

I'm using Font face to display Thonburi font on website http://www.mastersofbackgammon.net/site (English version)
and
http://www.mastersofbackgammon.net/site/index_ru.html (Russian version of the site)

I have the font displaying correctly on the English version of the site, but on the Russian version it works in some browsers and in some not. The font definitely has Cyrillic support, however I'm not sure how to configure it to display correctly in all browsers and computers.

Currently, I'm having issues with displaying cyrillic version in all of these browsers: Firefox, Internet Explorer, Opera, Chrome

When it doesn't display, the font is just Times New Roman.

What are solutions for this?

Comment: In what browsers are you *not* having problems?

Comment: my FF displays Cyrillic fine

Comment: Do you think there could be any reason why the font is not displaying correctly?

Comment: I think the question was inappropriately closed as “too localized”. The problem is not uncommon at all. But the question has now been re-posted as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232366/problems-displaying-custom-cyrillic-font-with-font-face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Thonburi and Thonburi Bold font as specified on the page have no Cyrillic letters (I checked this using OTMaster Light). This explains why Cyrillic letters are displayed using a fallback font, which is typically Times New Roman by default.

Comment: The font DID have originally the cyrillic letters. It is possible that when I generated the font files using this generator http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator the cyrillic letters were ignored. If this is the case how could I fix the issue?

Comment: @JohnSmith, in the FontSquirrel generator, select “EXPERT...” and then in “Subsetting”, select either “Custom Subsetting” and required languages or “No Subsetting”. The default there in “Basic Subsetting”, which includes “Western languages” only!